# Couchdb and dhtmlx library

Tags: couchdb, dhtmlx

I have created a small database (couchdb) and web page (html5 boilerplate).  My end goal is to have the user click a button which will retrieve a particular view which will be rendered as a table using the dhtmlx library (http://dhtmlx.com/).

At this point I have the page initializing the table (grid) on page load.  I am trying to load the data in to the table using 'mygrid.load(url,"json")'  The documentation doesn't provide an example of url but I'm assuming it would the be couchdb url of the view.  In my case that is:  127.0.0.1:5984/mydata/_design/mydata/_view/details.  If I open that url in a browser, I see the data in json format.

```
{"total_rows":14,"offset":0,"rows":[
{"id":"90e77126ce592105891eba2bd4000143","key":"An","value":"addition to others"},
{"id":"90e77126ce592105891eba2bd4001106","key":"Changed","value":"Directories."},
. . .
{"id":"83001c900adeefe50928a24b98001733","key":"Yeah","value":"CSS kind of working.  Guess I have express 3.0"}
]}
```

Needless to say:

```
mygrid.load("http://127.0.0.1:5984/mydata/_design/mydata/_view/details","json")
```

doesn't work.  So:

a)  Any ideas what I might be doing wrong?
b)  Are there better libraries for what I'm trying to do with the grid?  dhtmlx seems to be oriented to xml files, but it's what I was given.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Also check if your html is served from http:/ /127.0.0.1:5984. If it is not served from that address and port, than your javascript will not be able to issue request at all to http:/ /127.0.0.1:5984 because of [Same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy)

Sou you either have to serve your html from couchdb directly or use some proxy so that it appears they are served from same host and port.

Comment: My html page is served from 127.0.0.1:8080 (node.js server) and couchdb from 5984.  Where would an error appear signalling that the request could not be fulfilled?  My command line window shows "starting request messages" but no error.

Comment: well I am not familiar with mygrid, but in any case, it must issue http request to fetch the data, and any script that is in the page served from 127.0.0.1:8080 can issue request for the resources from to that same address and port. So there is no chance it could access json with data at http:/ /127.0.0.1:5984. So you must serve both html page, and couchdb form the same address and port

Answer (score 0):

It looks like dhtmlx supports JSON initialization:
http://www.dhtmlx.com/docs/products/dhtmlxGrid/samples/12_initialization_loading/09_init_grid_json.html

You will probably need to write some custom JavaScript to massage the CouchDB view output into a format that the Grid initializer supports.